# Precompiling assets failed and rake aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

Hello I tried to deploy my ruby on rails app to heroku and here is my error

```
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to whispering-peak-4064.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/whispering-peak-4064.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/whispering-peak-4064.git'
```

I saw many solutions here I tried to run those commands:

- `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`
- `rake asset:precompile`

And I got rake aborted!

I followed some answers found here I added to my `config\application.rb` :

```
require 'sprockets/railtie'
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

but in vain I still have the same problem.

PS: I am using Rails 4.2.5

Comment: Does precompiling locally work ? `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Yeah and this is what I got 

rake aborted!
Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializ               er:

  config.secret_key = 'dec618466f8a54a49e974325ccad03142a81235c32a5282b3294c9198               8ba06ccfde11f8ada06ba6a23c7bf37819811849bfeeaf2338b4093467331d862cb4a0d'

Please ensure you restarted your application after installing Devise or setting                the key.

Comment: Alright, and after you added that to `config/initializers/devise.rb` ?

Comment: Yup and I got this:
I, [2015-12-24T19:40:32.645619 #6452]  INFO -- : Writing C:/rubyy/forum/public/assets/applicati       on-9af8837e067e591b79c64f805ab6e96697b442699ba41cfcd18ac684e37bc7fa.js
I, [2015-12-24T19:40:32.890633 #6452]  INFO -- : Writing C:/rubyy/forum/public/assets/applicati       on-9af8837e067e591b79c64f805ab6e96697b442699ba41cfcd18ac684e37bc7fa.js.gz
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "  content: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "       : " ";"
(sass):27
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: Looks like an invalid extension, are you using .sass instead of .scss somewhere ? Can you post the full trace ?

Comment: C:\rubyy\forum\app\assets\stylesheets\application.css

Comment: Post the contents of application.CSS pls and a screenshot of your stylesheets folder

Comment: body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background: #1E90FF;
}
.wrapper {
 width: 60%;
 max-width: 1140px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
 content: : " ";
 display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
 clear: both;
}
.main_header #buttons {
    float: right;
    line-height: 60px;
 background: #DC143C;
    
    bottom: 0px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px;
}
.main_header {
 width: 100%;
}

Comment: #logo h1 {
    text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
#logo p {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}
#posts {
 background: white;
    
}
#logo {
 background: white;
    
    margin: 10px;
    color: #1E90FF;
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
} 
a { 
 margin: 50px;
 color:  black;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}
.date {
 font-size: 0.9rem;
 color: #1E90FF;
 margin: 50px;
}
.post {
 border-bottom:  1px solid #1E90FF;
}

Comment: #post_content {
    background: white;
     
}
#post_content h1 {
 font-weight: 100;
 font-size: 50px;
 color: #1E90FF;
 font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
 text-align: center;
}
#post_content p {
 margin: 20px;
}
#post_content a {
 font-size: 25px;
    background: #DC143C;
  
}

Comment: .comment_replier {
    color:  #1E90FF;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.wrapper h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive; 
}
.comment_content {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.comment{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #1E90FF;
 padding-bottom: 1em;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.content {
 width: 70%;
 float: left;
}
textarea {
 margin-left: 20px;
 min-height: 180px;
 border: 1px solid #1E90FF;

 width: 95%;
   font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;

}
input[type="submit"] {
 background: #1E90FF;
 color: white;
 padding: .5em 1em;
 
}

Comment: #comments h3 {
 margin-left: 20px;
 color: #1E90FF;
 font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
 font-size: 30px;
}
#comments h2 {
 margin-left: 20px;
 color: grey;
}
.optional {
font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive; 
font-size: 25px;
}
.wrapper a{
    font-size: 25px;
    background: #DC143C;
    
}

Comment: Please put it in your question and format it better, unreadable like this.

Comment: I can't publish the screenshots yet I don't have the abilities but I will publish the names of the folders:
application.css/comments.scss/posts.scss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this line is causing your error:

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: : " "; display: table; }
```

Should be

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: " "; display: table; }
```